# Where to put sugar during recipie editing on brewersfriend?

Tags: sugar, recipe-formulation

I'm putting recipe on brewersfriend and I want to add sugar at the end of boiling.

My question is in which section should I put it?

Fermentables (as late addition) or Other Ingredients (but it won't be taken into account during calculations)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd want to do it as a late-addition fermentable. From the [FAQ late addition entry](http://www.brewersfriend.com/faq/#recipes19):

> *"Use this to exclude the fermentable from the estimated boil gravity used in the calculator."*

This means you'll have the right gravity for bittering calculations during the boil, and the right post-boil gravity (reflecting the addition of sugar).

Comment: And what about malt added at the end of mashing? Should I also annotate it as late addition? (eg. CaraMunich II )

Comment: No, because you want the gravity it contributes to be taken into account for the boil. It should be entered as a regular fermentable.